# file rerendering on save

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import arcade from "../assets/images/icon-arcade.svg";
import advanced from "../assets/images/icon-advanced.svg";
import pro from "../assets/images/icon-pro.svg";

const SelectYourPlan = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(0);
  const [init, setInit] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(toggle);
    console.log(init);
    if (toggle === 0) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("ball")[0].style.marginLeft = "0vw";
      document.getElementById("left").style.color = "hsl(213, 96%, 18%)";
      document.getElementById("right").style.color = "hsl(231, 11%, 63%)";

      if (init === false) {
        let arcade = document.getElementsByClassName("arcade")[0];
        let advanced = document.getElementsByClassName("advanced")[0];
        let pro = document.getElementsByClassName("pro")[0];

        let arcadePrice = document.getElementById("arcadePrice");
        let advancedPrice = document.getElementById("advancedPrice");
        let proPrice = document.getElementById("proPrice");

        arcadePrice.textContent = "$9/month";
        advancedPrice.textContent = "$12/month";
        proPrice.textContent = "$15/month";

        arcade.removeChild(arcade.lastElementChild);
        advanced.removeChild(advanced.lastElementChild);
        pro.removeChild(pro.lastElementChild);
      }
    } else {
      let extraContentElement = document.createElement("p");
      extraContentElement.textContent = "2 months free";

      let arcade = document.getElementsByClassName("arcade")[0];
      let advanced = document.getElementsByClassName("advanced")[0];
      let pro = document.getElementsByClassName("pro")[0];

      let arcadePrice = document.getElementById("arcadePrice");
      let advancedPrice = document.getElementById("advancedPrice");
      let proPrice = document.getElementById("proPrice");

      arcadePrice.textContent = "$90/year";
      advancedPrice.textContent = "$120/year";
      proPrice.textContent = "$150/year";

      arcade.appendChild(extraContentElement.cloneNode(true));
      advanced.appendChild(extraContentElement.cloneNode(true));
      pro.appendChild(extraContentElement.cloneNode(true));

      arcade.lastElementChild.id = "arcade-free";
      advanced.lastElementChild.id = "advanced-free";
      pro.lastElementChild.id = "pro-free";

      document.getElementsByClassName("ball")[0].style.marginLeft = "1vw";
      document.getElementById("right").style.color = "hsl(213, 96%, 18%)";
      document.getElementById("left").style.color = "hsl(231, 11%, 63%)";
    }
  }, [toggle]);
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (toggle === 0) {
      setToggle(1);
      setInit(false);
    } else {
      setToggle(0);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <h1> Select your plan</h1>
      <Subtitle>You have the option of monthly or yearly billing.</Subtitle>
      <Flex>
        <Arcade imgUrl={arcade} className="arcade">
          <Title>Arcade</Title> <Price id="arcadePrice">$9/mo</Price>
        </Arcade>
        <Advanced imgUrl={advanced} className="advanced">
          <Title>Advanced</Title>
          <Price id="advancedPrice">$12/mo</Price>
        </Advanced>
        <Pro imgUrl={pro} className="pro">
          <Title>Pro</Title>
          <Price id="proPrice">$15/mo</Price>
        </Pro>
      </Flex>
      <SwitchBar>
        <Left id="left">Monthly</Left>
        <Switch onClick={handleClick}>
          <Ball className="ball"></Ball>
        </Switch>
        <Right id="right">Yearly</Right>
      </SwitchBar>
      <GoBack>Go Back</GoBack>
      <Next>Next Step</Next>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Actually I have a toggle switch whenever I click on that (when toggle state becomes 1) I want a extra sentence to display at the last in each of 'arcade','advanced','pro' components. This works fine but when I make some changes and save the file on the same toggle position (toggle=1) the statements keep on adding. If I do this on toggle=0 they start to get deleted as per the code. Maybe this is because the page re-renders on saving but is there any way to stop this as this poses great problem in debugging.

Comment: This is absolutely not how React is meant to be used. When using React, you should never use any of `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementById`, `style`, `textContent`, `removeChild`, `createElement`, `cloneNode`, `id`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to completely misunderstand the way React is meant to be used. You should not use `id`, `class`, or any of `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementById`, `style`, `textContent`, `removeChild`, `createElement`, `cloneNode`, etc.

Instead you should simply return something different depending on the current state and let React deal with DOM manipulation. Here is a cleaned up version of your code.
Note that we're simply returning different things depending on whether `showYearly` is true or false.
I renamed `toggle` to `showYearly` for clarity and removed `init` as I have no idea what it's meant to do.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import arcade from "../assets/images/icon-arcade.svg";
import advanced from "../assets/images/icon-advanced.svg";
import pro from "../assets/images/icon-pro.svg";

const SelectYourPlan = () => {
  const [showYearly, setShowYearly] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowYearly(showYearly => !showYearly);
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <h1> Select your plan</h1>
      <Subtitle>You have the option of monthly or yearly billing.</Subtitle>
      <Flex>
        <Arcade imgUrl={arcade}>
          <Title>Arcade</Title>
          <Price>{showYearly ? "$90/year" : "$9/mo"}</Price>
          {showYearly && <p>2 months free</p>}
        </Arcade>
        <Advanced imgUrl={advanced}>
          <Title>Advanced</Title>
          <Price>{showYearly ? "$120/year" : "$12/mo"}</Price>
          {showYearly && <p>2 months free</p>}
        </Advanced>
        <Pro imgUrl={pro}>
          <Title>Pro</Title>
          <Price>{showYearly ? "$150/year" : "$15/mo"}</Price>
          {showYearly && <p>2 months free</p>}
        </Pro>
      </Flex>
      <SwitchBar>
        <Left $showYearly={showYearly}>Monthly</Left>
        <Switch onClick={handleClick}>
          <Ball $showYearly={showYearly}/>
        </Switch>
        <Right $showYearly={showYearly}>Yearly</Right>
      </SwitchBar>
      <GoBack>Go Back</GoBack>
      <Next>Next Step</Next>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

For the style on `Left`, `Right` and `Ball`, you should use transient props from `styled-components`. For instance:

```js
const Left = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.$showYearly ? "hsl(213, 96%, 18%)" : "hsl(231, 11%, 63%)"};
  [...]
`;
```

Comment: Thanks greatly appreciated. I want to ask a question are styled-components really worth using because any state manipulation can be done in traditional react component but not inside the styled component.

Comment: The end of my answer shows how you use styled-components together with changing state, is there something unclear in my explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use React's state management keeping track of added elements and only add/remove as needed when toggle changes.

Something like this as reference, do adapt to your code, this is only an example.

```
const [addedElements, setAddedElements] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (toggle === 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("ball")[0].style.marginLeft = "0vw";
    document.getElementById("left").style.color = "hsl(213, 96%, 18%)";
    document.getElementById("right").style.color = "hsl(231, 11%, 63%)";

    if (init === false) {
      let arcade = document.getElementsByClassName("arcade")[0];
      let advanced = document.getElementsByClassName("advanced")[0];
      let pro = document.getElementsByClassName("pro")[0];

      let arcadePrice = document.getElementById("arcadePrice");
      let advancedPrice = document.getElementById("advancedPrice");
      let proPrice = document.getElementById("proPrice");

      arcadePrice.textContent = "$9/month";
      advancedPrice.textContent = "$12/month";
      proPrice.textContent = "$15/month";

      // Only remove elements if they were added before
      if (addedElements.includes("arcade-free")) {
        arcade.removeChild(document.getElementById("arcade-free"));
      }
      if (addedElements.includes("advanced-free")) {
        advanced.removeChild(document.getElementById("advanced-free"));
      }
      if (addedElements.includes("pro-free")) {
        pro.removeChild(document.getElementById("pro-free"));
      }
    }
  } else {
    let extraContentElement = document.createElement("p");
    extraContentElement.textContent = "2 months free";

    let arcade = document.getElementsByClassName("arcade")[0];
    let advanced = document.getElementsByClassName("advanced")[0];
    let pro = document.getElementsByClassName("pro")[0];

    let arcadePrice = document.getElementById("arcadePrice");
    let advancedPrice = document.getElementById("advancedPrice");
    let proPrice = document.getElementById("proPrice");

    arcadePrice.textContent = "$90/year";
    advancedPrice.textContent = "$120/year";
    proPrice.textContent = "$150/year";

    // Only add elements if they haven't been added before
    if (!addedElements.includes("arcade-free")) {
      arcade.appendChild(extraContentElement.cloneNode(true));
      arcade.lastElementChild.id = "arcade-free";
      setAddedElements(prevAddedElements => [...prevAddedElements, "arcade-free"]);
    }
    if (!addedElements.includes("advanced-free")) {
      advanced.appendChild(extraContentElement.cloneNode(true));
      advanced.lastElementChild.id = "advanced-free";
```

Edit: Since this is not how you should be using React, here is an example of how to properly use React state to store the prices and render them

```
const [prices, setPrices] = useState({
  arcade: "$9/month",
  advanced: "$12/month",
  pro: "$15/month"
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (toggle === 1) {
    setPrices({
      arcade: "$90/year",
      advanced: "$120/year",
      pro: "$150/year"
    });
  } else {
    setPrices({
      arcade: "$9/month",
      advanced: "$12/month",
      pro: "$15/month"
    });
  }
}, [toggle]);

...

<Arcade imgUrl={arcade} className="arcade">
  <Title>Arcade</Title>
  <Price>{prices.arcade}</Price>
</Arcade>
<Advanced imgUrl={advanced} className="advanced">
  <Title>Advanced</Title>
  <Price>{prices.advanced}</Price>
</Advanced>
<Pro imgUrl={pro} className="pro">
  <Title>Pro</Title>
  <Price>{prices.pro}</Price>
</Pro>
```

Comment: This is not at all how React should be used.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie Could you elaborate? I was simply giving a solution to what he already had in place. Edit: I understand what you mean, I have added another piece of code to refer

Comment: This is slightly better but there is still no point in using a useEffect and a different useState, there is already a useState that can be used directly (toggle).

Comment: Sorry about that, I did use React a bit like 3 years ago, right now I only use it to develop Azure DevOps extensions. I saw your code, I understand what was lacking now.

Comment: Thanks greatly appreciated for the help.